# In a React.js + react-router + Flux app, how do I send someone out of the app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a function logout which clears all state from my app. I then want it to send the customer to the marketing website which is hosted in a different stack on a different domain.

browserHistory doesn't have a function to do this.

Is there a function, or should I just be using location.href?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `location.href` for this sort of thing because you essentially need to do a full page reload to a different domain.

You cant do it with browserHistory as it uses HTML5 History API `pushState`, `replaceState` and `popstate` under the hood (in the https://github.com/mjackson/history repo) and this isnt supported in the spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method

> The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise,
>   pushState() will throw an exception